# Code won't work on the server?

Tags: html, css

On my computer it works fine but as soon as I upload it, it stops working, and I dont know why. Check out the link to see it going disastrously wrong.

```
    http://www.coachella.eu/
```

I dont understand why it wont work because it is sourced from here;
https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Coachella - Images</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">    
    </head>


    <body>
        <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
        <section id="photos">
            <img src="images/2015/1.jpg" alt="Hipster Girl">
            <img src="images/2015/2.jpg" alt="Beyonce">
            <img src="images/2015/3.jpg" alt="Azealia banks">
            <img src="images/2015/4.jpg" alt="Hipster">
            <img src="images/2015/5.jpg" alt="Girlfriends">
            <img src="images/2015/6.jpg" alt="Fake Tan">
            <img src="images/2015/7.jpg" alt="Paris Hilton?">
            <img src="images/2015/8.jpg" alt="Some C List Celebrity">
            <img src="images/2015/9.jpg" alt="Group of Californian girls">
            <img src="images/2015/10.jpg" alt="Sunset">
            <img src="images/2015/11.jpg" alt="Pouting & Sun Tans">
            <img src="images/2015/12.jpg" alt="Giant Spaceman">
            <img src="images/2015/13.jpg" alt="Girl with American Flag">
            <img src="images/2015/14.jpg" alt="4 tanned girls, one white one">
            <img src="images/2015/15.jpg" alt="Girls in white dresses">
            <img src="images/2015/16.jpg" alt="Showing skin and american flag">
            <img src="images/2015/18.jpg" alt="Cute couple">
            <img src="images/2015/19.jpg" alt="The crowd">
            <img src="images/2015/20.jpg" alt="Big Wheel">
            <img src="images/2015/21.jpg" alt="Girls eating">
            <img src="images/2015/22.jpg" alt="Grassy field">
            <img src="images/2015/24.jpg" alt="Packed crowd">
            <img src="images/2015/25.jpg" alt="Couples holding hands">
            <img src="images/2015/26.jpg" alt="Over Accessorised">
            <img src="images/2015/27.jpg" alt="Kardashian Girls">
            <img src="images/2015/28.jpg" alt="One of the Kardashians">
            <img src="images/2015/30.jpg" alt="Girl with open dress">
            <img src="images/2015/31.jpg" alt="Breaking Bad's Aaron Paul">
            <img src="images/2015/33.jpg" alt="Drone shot of crowd">
            <img src="images/2015/34.jpg" alt="Paris Hilton">
        </section>
    </body>
```

CSS is working fine on my computer too!!

```
body {
        padding: 0px;
        @apply(--layout-fullbleed);
        @apply(--paper-font-common-base);
    }

    #photos {
        /* Prevent vertical gaps */
        line-height: 0;

        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
        -moz-column-count:    5;
        -moz-column-gap:      0px;
        column-count:         5;
        column-gap:           0px;  
    }

    #photos img {
        /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        #photos {
            -moz-column-count:    5;
            -webkit-column-count: 5;
            column-count:         5;
        }
        #photos img {
            /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
            max-width:  width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        #photos {
            -moz-column-count:    3;
            -webkit-column-count: 3;
            column-count:         3;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
        #photos {
            -moz-column-count:    2;
            -webkit-column-count: 2;
            column-count:         2;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        #photos {
            -moz-column-count:    1;
            -webkit-column-count: 1;
            column-count:         1;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: The files are 100% on the server, i've deleted them and re-uploaded them all! Not sure why it's not finding them because the links are directly to the files.

Comment: Have you uploaded the images?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the images to be visible on the web, they need to be available on the server with the path file you have mentioned... So basically you need to make sure that those images are available on the server. This should explain everything: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3478181

Comment: How about you post a screenshot where the pictures are stored and also post a screenshot on what the design webpage looks like when loaded up.

Answer (score 0):

All of your current images, I'm guessing, are stored locally on the computer.

If you fail to upload the images as well, then you won't be able to see them!

On thing I suggest is replicating the path that is being used, and copy the entire folders over.

So, if you have a project saved locally, on your computer, in a folder, then upload the **entire** contents of the folder to your public_html folder.

The little 'broken images' that you're seeing indicate that your files haven't been found, normally.

Hope you can fix it!